# Basic Floating Point Questions?

Tags: math, binary, floating-point, addition, cpu-architecture

I read following example on Book:

[image]

I think the last Representation should be { 0 | 1 0 0 0 1 | 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 } because 11.10111010 in normalized form is 1.110111010. is there any wrong?

Comment: When doing calculations, always apply basic principles to check your answers. We are adding two different positive numbers. The result must be bigger than the larger of the two inputs, but less than twice the larger input. The only possible result exponents are 10010 and 10011.

Answer (score 1):

You have take the same convention forward as backwards. The example does not use the implicit leading 1/hidden bit and is totally consistent in that.

To demonstrate the contrary option, if your normalization includes an implicit leading 1/hidden bit, then the addend/augend and result should be

```
 111.001000
+  1.10011010
--------------
1000.10111010
```

leading to the binary encoded result

```
0|10011|00010111
```

Comment: 11.10111010 in normalized form is 1.110111010 is it okey?

Comment: You claim the implicit leading 1 for the backward encoding from number to floating point memory format. But then you should also apply this convention to the preceding conversion of the operands from memory format to number.

Comment: I don't think this example format has a hidden bit.

Comment: @DigitalRoss: I'll edit that in, I tried to show that with the hidden bit the whole example would look different.

Comment: @LoveComplexity: Normalization applies to the interpretation of the memory format. Your two numbers just demonstrate a division by 2.

Comment: @LutzL my question is on re-normalized part.

Comment: Obviously, the translation from binary encoding to number used in the example is from `(s|e|m)` to`(-)^s · 2^(e-16) · 0.m`, as one can confirm from the treatment of the operands. The encoding of the result has to follow the same scheme. For it to be a "normalized" encoding, the first mantissa bit always has to be `1`, which is a waste and thus omitted in "real" encodings.

Comment: could ask me one example to normalize it and check I convert it correctly or not?

Comment: Ok, try 0.01001 and 1101.01

Answer (score 1):

These are all the same number:  **0.111*2<sup>2</sup>,   1.11*2<sup>1</sup>,   11.1*2<sup>0</sup>**.    It looks like the example format doesn't have a hidden bit and places the binary point at the left.

Comment: MY QUESTION is on re-normalizing section. !!

Comment: Sure, my point is that `x.y` normalization is just one way to do it.  In this format, normalization apparently means `.xy`, which makes sense if there is no hidden bit.

Comment: you means  { 0 | 1 0 0 0 1 | 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 } with last figure in my question is same

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the answers and comments, I think there may be a basic misunderstanding of the term "normalization". **Normalization does not imply a hidden bit.**

It only means that the most significant non-zero digit will have a specific position relative to the radix point. For example, in decimal, 1 might be represented as 100*10<sup>-2</sup>, 10*10<sup>-1</sup>, 1*10<sup>0</sup>, 0.1*10<sup>1</sup> etc. A normalized system might require the use of e.g. 0.1*10<sup>1</sup>, putting the "1" digit immediately to the right of the decimal point.

In a binary normalized system, one of the bits is known to be one. Not storing that bit is a common choice, but is not required by being a normalized system.

In the case of the example, it is clear from how the inputs were expressed in the summation that there is no hidden bit, the normalized form has the most significant bit immediately to the right of the binary point, and unbiased exponent 0 is represented as 10000.

Binary 11.10111010 is equal to binary 0.1110111010 with unbiased exponent decimal 2, binary 10. That makes the biased exponent 10010, and the significand the leftmost bits of 1110111010.